# Command line Git doesn't recognize keys generated using GitHub for Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

I've setup GitHub for Windows and used it to create SSH keys which are associated with my account. I can perform git operations in the GitHub for Windows GUI, but when I try to run a command in Command Prompt like `git clone git@github.com:whatever.git` I get an error like the following:

```
C:\Users\Nat\Documents\GitHub>git clone git@github.com:natdempk/whatever.git
Cloning into 'whatever'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why is this happening when everything works from the GitHub for Windows GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When GitHub for Windows creates keys they are named `github_rsa` and `github_rsa.pub`. `git` expects keys to be named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` by default, so it will not find the keys from GitHub for Windows and will give you `Permission denied (publickey)`. To fix this you should create an SSH config file for `github.com` as `C:\users\<username>\.ssh\config` that looks something like the following:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

This informs `git` to use the generated GitHub for Windows keys when performing operations that connect to `github.com`.